# access sql criteria date 3 months ago

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, format, criteria

I need to filter a table and show only result that are 3 months ago. So if it is August, to show me May.

Here is my query sql code:

```
SELECT tblAppointment.WorkID, tblAppointment.AppointmentDate, tblCustomer.CustomerID 
FROM tblWork INNER JOIN (tblCustomer INNER JOIN tblAppointment ON tblCustomer.CustomerID = tblAppointment.CustomerID) ON tblWork.WorkID = tblAppointment.WorkID 
GROUP BY tblAppointment.WorkID, tblAppointment.AppointmentDate, tblCustomer.CustomerID 
HAVING (((tblAppointment.WorkID)=3) AND ((tblAppointment.AppointmentDate) Between Format(DateAdd("m",-3,Date()),"m") And Format(DateAdd("m",-4,Date()),"m"))) 
ORDER BY tblAppointment.AppointmentDate, tblCustomer.CustomerID;
```

I am getting a error. I am trying to fix HAVING part.

Please help.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The HAVING clause is for aggregate function conditions. Put regular conditions in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Why are you grouping? You're not using any group function.... Like Peter Abolins wrote, place your error. Just to try: remove that entire group by and change your "having" with a "where" clause.

Comment: Data type mismatch in criteria expression. (Error 3464)

Comment: if I delete BETWEEN ... TO part it is working. So the error is there

Comment: What is the error? What is the schema? What should the query do? So many questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always handle dates as dates, not text:

```
SELECT 
    tblAppointment.WorkID, 
    tblAppointment.AppointmentDate, 
    tblCustomer.CustomerID 
FROM 
    tblWork 
INNER JOIN 
    (tblCustomer 
    INNER JOIN tblAppointment 
    ON tblCustomer.CustomerID = tblAppointment.CustomerID) 
    ON tblWork.WorkID = tblAppointment.WorkID 
WHERE
    tblAppointment.AppointmentDate 
    Between 
        DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date())-3, 1)
    And 
        DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date())-2, 0)
GROUP BY 
    tblAppointment.WorkID, 
    tblAppointment.AppointmentDate, 
    tblCustomer.CustomerID 
HAVING 
    tblAppointment.WorkID=3
ORDER BY 
    tblAppointment.AppointmentDate, 
    tblCustomer.CustomerID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error, and the code, it looks like you are trying to compare dates to strings. Regardless of the `GroupBy` / `Having` constructs being necessary, change the Date comparison to:

```
and DatePart("m", Date()) - DatePart("m", tblAppointment.AppointmentDate)) = 3
```

You may need to modify to cover the case for the beginning / end of year.

```
AND (
        (
            Year(Date()) = Year(tblAppointment.AppointmentDate) 
            AND 
            DatePart("m", Date()) - DatePart("m", tblAppointment.AppointmentDate) = 3
        )
    OR
        (
            Year(Date()) > Year(tblAppointment.AppointmentDate) 
            AND
            DatePart("m", Date()) + 12 - DatePart("m", tblAppointment.AppointmentDate) = 3
        )
    )
```